# Using HtmlHelper in a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use HtmlHelper in a controller, for-example to get the TextBox(...) method? not that I can't write the html that it generates myself, but I just want to understand how this works so I can create the best solution.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here's an example adapted from [this](http://www.brightmix.com/blog/how-to-renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/):

```
var h = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView("omg"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary()), new ViewPage());
h.TextBox("myname");
```

Note that this is a hack, it can be done but I don't think there's any good reason to do this...

Comment: I don't think it's a fantastic thing to do either, but I'm using Telerik grid controls that use AJAX, and when using AJAX, the ClientTemplate for a column must be pre-rendered text - it's not going to be able to resolve the action on the client. That's _my_ reason for looking this up, at any rate. I'd prefer the controls didn't work this way, but if it's the price I pay for having controls light-years better than anything I could do, then it's something I'll work around.

Comment: this example is not valid now

Comment: @Anubis : what do you mean by 'now'? ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: You can get away with just 'var htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage());' now. One good reason to use this is to generate antiforgerytokens. I've done just that to enable CSRF protection on a legacy asp3.0 system that was proxied through an MVC controller.

Comment: @Stimul8d - Your comment has more upvotes than some of the other answers here. Wish you would add this as an official answer, as this was the most straightforward approach that worked for me.

Answer (score 32):

You can use method like this:

```
public static HtmlHelper GetHtmlHelper(this Controller controller)
{
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, new FakeView(), controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, TextWriter.Null);
    return new HtmlHelper(viewContext, new ViewPage());
}

public class FakeView : IView
{
    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: think to add "using System.Web.Mvc.Html;" to get all HtmlHelper extension (this is with MVC 3)

Comment: A nice way to use htmlhelper in controller with mvc 3 is to call Partial method to render html of a view (for example to use razor view as template html email)

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for, works like a charm. Thank you for sharing this code.

Answer (score 9):

The HtmlHelper is part of the View mechanism by design and should be considered separate to the Controller and Model parts of MVC. I am not sure why you would want to generate controls inside the controller as it's role is to deliver the Data to the view for rendering.

I am not saying that you cannot achieve it, but for good design it would be better.

Can you explain what you are trying to achieve and then we could look at doing it in an "MVC way"?

Comment: I was using it as a way to generate the control's html based on a user selection in an ajax form. Trying to get the same concept as Rails RJS forms. Although the provided solution did work, I agree that this is not the cleanest solution and I will probably end up making it all client side after all.

Answer (score 6):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

var h = new HtmlHelper<Effort>(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView(ControllerContext, "omg"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), new StringWriter()), new ViewPage());

h.DisplayFor(e => Model.Efforts[i].Content.Offer.Price1.Value)
```

Comment: this helped me .

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core 2 MVC: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7321

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


    public class HelperGenerator
    {
        private readonly IHtmlGenerator _htmlGenerator;
        private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _compositeViewEngine;
        private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;
        private readonly IViewBufferScope _viewBufferScope;
        private readonly IActionContextAccessor _actionContextAccessor;
        private readonly HtmlHelperOptions _htmlHelperOptions;

        public HelperGenerator(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator, ICompositeViewEngine compositeViewEngine, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider, IViewBufferScope viewBufferScope, IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor, IOptions<MvcViewOptions> options)
        {
            _htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator;
            _compositeViewEngine = compositeViewEngine;
            _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
            _viewBufferScope = viewBufferScope;
            _actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
            _htmlHelperOptions = options.Value.HtmlHelperOptions;
        }
        public IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper(ViewDataDictionary ViewData, ITempDataDictionary TempData)
        {
            var helper = new HtmlHelper(_htmlGenerator, _compositeViewEngine, _modelMetadataProvider, _viewBufferScope, HtmlEncoder.Default, UrlEncoder.Default);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(_actionContextAccessor.ActionContext,
               new FakeView(),
               ViewData,
               TempData,
               TextWriter.Null,
               _htmlHelperOptions);
            helper.Contextualize(viewContext);
            return helper;
        }
        private class FakeView : IView
        {
            public string Path => "View";

            public Task RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure to register in services:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to do this from without a Controller (like when unit testing), there are further problems to deal with, as many of these methods (which I know, were not a testing scenario, but for that scenario) were throwing Null exceptions (`ViewContext.ScopeCache`). You can see this by the following (note all of these ways require a `ViewContext` instance to be formed, which is one of the parameters you insert into the constructor of the HtmlHelper instance, so on that object):

```
viewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false;
```

Simply setting that value throws an exception with many of these methods, but the problem was fixed for me [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216750/264031), see how he gets an `HtmlHelper` (see also [here](https://gist.github.com/ErikSchierboom/6da474dcd5751fbbc94c)).

Answer (score 0):

- using System.Web.Mvc;
- using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

  ```
   HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new            WebFormView(ControllerContext, "Index"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), new System.IO.StringWriter()), new ViewPage());
  ```