# Create HtmlHelper<T> in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a create an `HtmlHelper<T>` in a Controller ([see this for the non-generic version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083713/create-htmlhelper-instance-in-controller)).

This is what I have done so far:

```
public static HtmlHelper<TData> CreatePseudoHelper<TData>(this Controller Source, TData Model)
{
    Source.ViewData.Model = Model;
    return new HtmlHelper<TData>(new ViewContext(Source.ControllerContext, new PseudoView(), Source.ViewData, Source.TempData, TextWriter.Null), new ViewPage());
}


public class PseudoView : IView
{
    public void Render(ViewContext Context, TextWriter Writer)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot render a pseudo view.");
    }
}
```

However, when the created `HtmlHelper` is returned, the embedded `ViewData` has a null `Model`.  When I step through, the `Model` is definitely not null when it is set to the `ViewData.Model` of the source, but as soon as this is used to create the `HtmlHelper`, it becomes null.

What am I missing?