# ASP MVC - Manually execute child action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing a custom view engine for ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to add support for child actions. Below is the handler that should execute the child action and return the results as a string. Everything is working correctly up until this point; the method is called when it should be and the parameters are all populated correctly.

```
private string HandleActionHelper(ViewContext viewContext, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        var routeData = new RouteData();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
            controllerName = viewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string;

        routeData.Values["action"] = actionName;
        routeData.Values["controller"] = controllerName;
        foreach(var value in routeValues)
        {
            routeData.Values.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
        }

        var requestContext = new RequestContext(viewContext.HttpContext, routeData);
        var mvcHandler = new MvcHandler(requestContext);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        viewContext.HttpContext.Server.Execute(mvcHandler, writer, true);

        return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
```

It throws a `System.Web.HttpException` on `viewContext.HttpContext.Server.Execute(mvcHandler, writer, true);`.

The full error message reads:

> Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler'.

I've been searching online and looking through the MVC sources to see how, and this was my best stab at it without just copy/pasting a lot of the `internal` MVC classes.

How can I go about executing a child action and getting the results back as a string?

**Edit:** Adding full stack trace

> System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(System.Web.IHttpHandler
>   handler, System.IO.TextWriter writer, bool preserveForm, bool
>   setPreviousPage, System.Web.VirtualPath path, System.Web.VirtualPath
>   filePath, string physPath, System.Exception error, string
>   queryStringOverride)  Unknown
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(System.Web.IHttpHandler
>   handler, System.IO.TextWriter writer, bool preserveForm, bool
>   setPreviousPage)  Unknown
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(System.Web.IHttpHandler
>   handler, System.IO.TextWriter writer, bool preserveForm)  Unknown
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(System.Web.IHttpHandler
>   handler, System.IO.TextWriter writer, bool preserveForm)  Unknown
>   JadeViewEngine.dll!JadeViewEngine.JadeView.HandleActionHelper(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext
>   viewContext, string actionName, string controllerName,
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues) Line 85  C#
>   JadeViewEngine.dll!JadeViewEngine.JadeView.Render.AnonymousMethod__0(dynamic
>   input) Line 39    C# edge_nativeclr.node!ClrFunc.Call( value,  payload, 
>   callback) Unknown
>   edge_nativeclr.node!.clrFuncProxy(Nan.FunctionCallbackInfo*
>   info) Unknown [Native to Managed Transition]   [Managed to Native
>   Transition]
>   edge_nativeclr.node!.Nan.imp.?A0x8dda69af.FunctionCallbackWrapper(v8.FunctionCallbackInfo*
>   info) Unknown [Native to Managed Transition]   [Managed to Native
>   Transition]
>   edge_nativeclr.node!NodejsFuncInvokeContext.CallFuncOnV8Thread()  Unknown
>   edge_nativeclr.node!.clrActionContext.ActionCallback(void*
>   data) Unknown [Native to Managed Transition]   [Managed to Native
>   Transition]
>   edge_nativeclr.node!.continueOnV8Thread(uv_async_s* handle,
>   int status)   Unknown [Native to Managed Transition]   [Managed to Native
>   Transition]    EdgeJs.dll!EdgeJs.Edge.Func.AnonymousMethod__1()   Unknown
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object
>   state)    Unknown
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx)  Unknown
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx)  Unknown
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state)    Unknown
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  Unknown
>   [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: What's the full stack trace? I'm not sure this is the right approach - child actions normally work by triggering a child request on the same response stream, not by writing to a string.

Comment: @AntP Stack trace added to question. If you call `HtmlHelper.RenderAction()` in a Razor view, it writes to the stream, but if you call` HtmlHelper.Action()` it returns an `MvcString` that you can then call `ToString()` on.

Comment: Since posting this question, I have been trying to accomplish this by creating an instance of `HtmlHelper` and using its `Action()` method. This worked exactly how I want it to in my tests. The problem is that I am using Edge.js to execute some NodeJS code, and if I call `HtmlHelper.Action()` within my `HandleActionHelper()` method (which itself is called by NodeJS code), then the `Action()` method never returns and there are no errors or exceptions. I think fixing this would be off topic for this question. I'd still like to know if there is a more appropriate way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution to this was to create an instance of the `HtmlHelper` class you get in Razor views, and then use its `Action()` method to get the resulting string:

```
using System.Web.Mvc; // Bring in HtmlHelper
using System.Web.Mvc.Html; // Bring in HtmlHelper's extension methods.
...
var html = new HtmlHelper(viewContext, new ViewPage());
string actionResults = html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

**Note 1:** This is within a custom `IView` implementation for a custom view engine, so I just passed in the `ViewContext` instance I already had. If you don't have a `ViewContext` available, you'll have to create one. Here is an old example (so not sure how well it works), but it should help you get started: [Create HtmlHelper instance in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083713/create-htmlhelper-instance-in-controller)

**Note 2:** As mentioned in the comments of my original question, I was having trouble with this approach. As far as I can tell, `HtmlHelper` does not work well within an async context. I was using Edge.js to call NodeJS code, which is all async stuff, so I think this was the cause of these issues. When I move the calls to `HtmlHelper` outside of Edge.js, it worked fine.