# HtmlHelper in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need a HtmlHelper instance in my controller.

How can I instantiate one? thanks

This does not build:

```
var h = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView("omg"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary()), new ViewPage());
```

**Here is a screenshot of the error**
[image]

Also, when I look at the list of methods under `var h`, I only see my custom extension methods and no regular ones like `ActionLink`. So that one needs to list as well. **(solved by sternr)**

**Solution:**

1. Ensure System.Web.Mvc.Html is included.
2. Here is the code to instantiate a HtmlHelper.

   `System.IO.TextWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();`

   `var html = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView(ControllerContext, "omg"), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), writer), new ViewPage());`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HtmlHelper in a Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621235/using-htmlhelper-in-a-controller)

Comment: yes, but does not appear to work in mvc3

Comment: Add using System.Web.Mvc.Html in the controller.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HtmlHelper.ActionLink and most of the methods you'r probably looking for are extension methods declared under the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace.

As for instantiating\using HtmlHelper inside your controller - this is a bad practice as your clearly combine UI code with Controller code. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: thanks for the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace trick. I need to pass the HtmlHelper to a class library to do some work. I have updated my question with a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Voted down as does not answer question of how to get reference to HtmlHelper in controller.