# How do I get the HTML from an HTML.DropDownList in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I want to do get the HTML from an Html.DropDownList in a controller. This is the code I have so far:

```
var binMasters = repository.LoadBinsByZone(12345);
var ddl = new SelectList(binMasters, "BinID", "BinCode");
string result = ddl.ToString();
return result;
```

The result is "System.Web.Mvc.SelectList" instead of the HTML.
How do I get the HTML from an Html.DropDownList in the controller?

Comment: why you need the html???. I mean, Why do you try to accomplish???

Comment: I am making an AJAX call and want to update a div with a <select> element.

Comment: see my answer to handle html elements with razor and jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you just create a method in your controller that returns an action result which it's the html associated to the view that you want to render

```
//this if you want get the html by get
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View();
}
```

And the client called like this

```
$.get('your controller path', parameters to the controler , function callback)
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your controller path",
    data: parameters to the controler
    dataType: "html",
    success: your function
    });
```

Also you can load partial views, and render in a specific parts of your view with the jquery load which it's no more than a ajax called

Answer (score 1):

There is no "HTML DropDownList" in the Controller.  The HTML hasn't been rendered until it goes through the view.  (In fact, you specifically *shouldn't* want to have anything to do with the raw HTML or any View-level functionality within the Controller.  Those concerns should be distinctly separated.)

The reason it shows you `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectList"` is because what you're doing is calling `.ToString()` on a reference object (`ddl` which is of type `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList`).  The default behavior of `.ToString` on `object` is to return the name of the class.  (Which makes sense, given that `object` has no knowledge of what other functionality its descendants may present.)

A bigger question remains... *Why* do you need to do this?  As I said, the Controller shouldn't know or care about the View that's going to be generated from it.  Indeed, the Controller should be re-usable for other Views as well.  So it occurs to me that there's probably a much better way to solve the root problem you're facing if we take a step back.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var Html = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, new WebFormView(""), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary()), new ViewPage());
var result = Html.DropDownList("dropDownList", ddl).ToHtmlString();
```

Comment: Bala, thank your for the reply. When I tried it i got this error: 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tarzan check out the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/621235/273200