# Orchard MVC - Login with ajax and submit another form in current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, orchardcms

I have a form (POST) and anonymous can enter value in its input field. But if they want to submit, they must log in. I made a ajax login form and signin on my action, then i submit the first form, the system throw "**A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid**.".

What should I do for resolve this?
(sorry my english not good)

Answer (score 0):

Anti-forgery tokens are only really necessary for authenticated users, so what's happening here is that your ajax authentication method is not touching the other form, which didn't have a token because it was rendered when the user was anonymous. So what you need to do is to add the token dynamically as part of the callback from authentication, I suppose...

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand! I tried get a new token in my action but did not success. can you help me get a new token on a JsonResult action?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, because calling into the helper may not directly work if it needs context. I wish I could be more helpful but the best way to find out is probably to try to use the helpers for getting the token from the view, but from your action, and resolve the difficulties as you go.

Comment: hi @Bertrand, i tried to create a HtmlHelper in my action, like the way in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621235/using-htmlhelper-in-a-controller) i got the new token and replace the current token by it, but it sill getting error. is the new token that created in action not right?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't say what helper method you used or how you added it to the form.

Comment: ok @Bertrand, i have a new solution for my issue. thanks for read my first question.

Comment: Can you please share what you did, for others to enjoy? Also, if my answer helped you, please grant it as answer. Thanks.