# How can i call @Html.TextBoxFor in a .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project in for each textbox in a view i have the fallowing

```
<div class="field-box">
    <label>Titlu</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control inline-input" })
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

I want to write a custom helper that will output this for me, but i have no idea how to call @Html.TextBoxFor when i'm not in a view.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

**Update**
I found this [Using HtmlHelper in a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621235/using-htmlhelper-in-a-controller) but it looks terrible there has to be a better way

Comment: There is no other way directly. Why do you need to call this from the backend? You are probably going the wrong way about something if you need to call it outside of views.

Comment: @Karhgath because i don't know a better way to shorten the html i've pasted or to find a way to save it an reuse it. It's to much copy paste. I have that with different variables in about 20 places

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelper {

    public static MvcHtmlString MyFieldBox<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, String title) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"field-box\">");
        sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"field-box">\");
        sb.AppendLine("<label>{0}</label>", title);
        sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-md-7\">");
        sb.AppendLine( htmlHelper.TextBoxFor( expression, new { @class = "form-control inline-input" }) );
        sb.AppendLine("</div>");
        sb.AppendLine( htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor( expression );
        sb.AppendLine("</div>");
        return new MvcHtmlString( sb.ToString() );
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
<%= Html.MyFieldBox( m => m.Name, "Name" ) %>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, have to correct a view error give you the updated and mark it as correct.

Comment: i cannot for the life of me to import what i need to make Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression compile can you please help. It's says that it cannot resolve TProperty, if there's an import that i got wrong i don't know which. Thanks

Comment: You need a <TProperty> in the function definition, I just added this, try it now...

Comment: @Dai hi, Could you please consider answering this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23731814/50506 , which could be done in a similar approach to what you have mentioned here, there I want to use 2 properties of the model not the whole expression, If you wanted to convert the format into a more similar to your answer here, that should be OK or maybe even better, +1 here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option if this is only used within one view, is to use the razor htmlhelper syntax.

You define the helper like this:

```
@helper MyTextBoxFor(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<ViewModelType, object>> expression )
{
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Titlu</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "form-control inline-input" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression)
    </div>
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
@MyTextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, already marked the other one as correct. Would this helper be available in my entire project or just the view in which it's defined ?

Comment: Just the one view. There might be some way to share it by putting it in a layout, I'm not sure. Even if you did though, the big limitation is it doesn't support generics... so it would only work for the one view model. It's really only useful when you're using the same snippet in the same view, I think.

Comment: Here's how you can share it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx  but still the lack of generic support limits its usefulness in this case.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

But, as stated,

> The HtmlHelper class is designed to generate UI. It should not be used in controllers or models.

Answer (score 0):

You can try editor templates if that works for you

Comment: Hello, if editor templates are the same as t4 templates they're not the way i want to go, if their something different can you please provide a link

Comment: HI Toby . 
1) Add View under Views -> Shared -> EditorTemplates
2) Name the View same as your Viewmodel/Model(create New ViewModel/Model let's say personNameVM for this HTML content and add it using @model)
3) That's it, use that template as @html.EditorFor(m => m.personNameVM) wherever you want