# Double input mvc extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

Here I was trying to make an extension with **double input boxes**

the returned model's properties are null,
They are not correctly bound or there is another issue here,
please help me on writing this extension and make use of it.
I need to use thousands of it during my code.

```
public static class DoubleBoxHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DoubleBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        //int id, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var model = metadata.Model as DoubleNumber;
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        var fieldId = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(fullName);

        // 1st TextBox
        var tagInputLeft = new TagBuilder("input");
        tagInputLeft.Attributes.Add("name", fullName);
        tagInputLeft.Attributes.Add("id", fieldId + 1);
        tagInputLeft.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
        tagInputLeft.Attributes.Add("value", model.Num1 == null ? "" : model.Num1.ToString());

        // 2nd TextBox
        var tagInputRight = new TagBuilder("input");
        tagInputRight.Attributes.Add("name", fullName);
        tagInputRight.Attributes.Add("id", fieldId + 2);
        tagInputRight.Attributes.Add("type", "text");
        tagInputRight.Attributes.Add("value", model.Num2 == null ? "" : model.Num2.ToString());

        builder.Append(tagInputLeft.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        builder.Append(tagInputLeft.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

**The Model class**

```
public class DoubleNumber
{
    public int Num1 { get; set; } // tried strings but again they are null
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
}
```

And Here is the controller -Post action which we need the entered numbers

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DoubleNumber g)
{
    int iNum1 = g.Num1; // int or string doesn't matter, it couldn't get the entered(modified) model
    int iNum2 = g.Num2;
    var vm = ViewModelOf(g);
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: If anyone can also mention how can I use something similar to this: "htmlHelper.TextBoxFor( expression " inside my string builder which I can target my Model's needed properties through it, it could be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably have an easier time just using an editor template:

**Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DoubleNumber.cshtml**

```
@model DoubleNumber
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Num1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Num2)
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Or, if you've got a property of type `DoubleNumber` on a view model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDoubleNumberProperty)
```

Comment: That is OK I think +1, it could be similar to PartialView approach, but what if you are making a re-usable library and you are trying to put some similar logic as a control, Also I'm trying to find what I missed here, please consider the alternative way also, thanks