# Can we use Htmlhelper class in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on web api project, we have one htmlhelper class, where I see declarations that look like:

```
 public static string GetCountryDomain(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Area area)
                     {
                         //body
                     }
```

Can I use method declared in helper class in my api method?
If Yes, then can someone explain how can I call that method from my controller?

Consider following example, wherein am calling method declared in helper from my controller.

```
HtmlHelper.GetCountryDomain(area_id);
```

can someone explain what first parameter I need to pass in order to call above method of HtmlHelper class?

Comment: You might want to read about [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HtmlHelper in a Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621235/using-htmlhelper-in-a-controller)