# Add Html.ActionLink in every row in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I  a Jqgrid that displays students data, I don't want to use Jgrid toolbar buttons for editing or deleting.

so I want additional column that have something like this

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StudentID }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StudentID }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.StudentID })
```

here is my StudentGridModel :

```
  public class StudentsGridModel
{
    public StudentsGridModel()
    {
        StudentsGrid = new JQGrid
        {
            Columns = new List<JQGridColumn>()
            {
                              new JQGridColumn { DataField = "StudentID",
                                                    PrimaryKey = true,
                                                    Editable = false,
                                                    HeaderText = "ID",
                                                    TextAlign = Jq.Grid.TextAlign.Center,
                                                    Width = 50},
                                  new JQGridColumn { DataField = "FullName", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    HeaderText = "Full Name",
                                                    Width = 175
                                                    },
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "BirthDate", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    HeaderText = "Birth Date",
                                                    Width = 125 },
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "Photo", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    HeaderText = "Photo",
                                                    Width = 175
                                                    },
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "Gender", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    HeaderText = "Gender",
                                                    Width = 100
                                                    },
                                  new JQGridColumn { DataField = "Country", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    HeaderText = "Country",
                                                    Width = 100
                                                    },
                                  new JQGridColumn { DataField = "MobileNumber", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    HeaderText = "Mobile Number",
                                                    Width = 100
                                                    },
                                  new JQGridColumn { DataField = "Email", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    HeaderText = "Email",
                                                    Width = 100
                                                    }
            },
            Height = Unit.Percentage(100),
            Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
        };
        StudentsGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowRefreshButton = true;
    }
    public JQGrid StudentsGrid { get; set; }
}
```

Teacher Controller :

```
// GET: Teacher
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var gridModel = new StudentsGridModel();
        var grid = gridModel.StudentsGrid;
        SetUpGrid(grid);

        return View(gridModel);
    }
    private void SetUpGrid(JQGrid grid)
    {
        grid.ID = "StudentsGrid";
        grid.DataUrl = Url.Action("DataRequested");
        grid.SortSettings.AutoSortByPrimaryKey = false;
        grid.SortSettings.InitialSortColumn = "FullName";
        grid.SortSettings.InitialSortDirection = SortDirection.Asc;

        grid.ToolBarSettings.ShowEditButton = false;
        grid.ToolBarSettings.ShowAddButton = false;
        grid.ToolBarSettings.ShowDeleteButton = true;

        SetUpVirtualScrollingGrid(grid);
    }
    private void SetUpVirtualScrollingGrid(JQGrid grid)
    {
        grid.PagerSettings.ScrollBarPaging = true;
        grid.PagerSettings.PageSize = 20;
        grid.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(400);
    }
    public JsonResult DataRequested()
    {
        StudentsGridModel gridModel = new StudentsGridModel();
        var data = from s in db.Students
                   select new
                   {
                       s.StudentID,
                       s.FullName,
                       s.BirthDate,
                       s.Photo,
                       s.Gender,
                       s.Country,
                       s.MobileNumber,
                       s.Email
                   };
        return gridModel.StudentsGrid.DataBind(data);
    }
```

Comment: one way is just form your href as a string in your model.

Comment: Well, I can't just store it as datafield because it returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What do you mean? It sounds like it's usual null reference exception now.

Comment: show how do you form url.

Comment: DataField = "@Html.ActionLink('Edit', 'Edit', new { id=StudentID })"

Comment: wait, are you using this helper in your controller?

Comment: No, I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could form your string in controller. If you really want to use HtmlHelper inside controller here in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621261/1849444) how to do it.

But better just form string with a href yourself.

Form column:

```
new JQGridColumn
{
    DataField = "Edit",
    Editable = false,
    HeaderText = "Edit",
    Width = 100
}
```

Add string data to it:

```
StudentsGridModel gridModel = new StudentsGridModel();
        var data = from s in db.Students
                   select new
                   {
                       s.StudentID,
                       s.FullName,
                       s.BirthDate,
                       s.Photo,
                       s.Gender,
                       s.Country,
                       s.MobileNumber,
                       s.Email,
                       Edit = String.Format(@"<a href='/Student/Edit/{0})'>Edit</a>", s.StudentID)
                   };
```

But you should understand that you must have controller `Student` with method `Edit` that return you View.

Comment: It give me Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. I'm going to give using Htmlhelper inside a controller a try and see what happens.

Comment: that's other kind of problem try change like this:

`Edit = String.Format(@"<a href='/Student/Edit/{0})'>Edit</a>", s.StudentID)`. Html Helper approach will do the same thing in the end.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but first it gave me an error that LINQ doesn't recognize String.Format so I changed the line to this ` @"<a href='/Teacher/Edit/" + s.StudentID +"'>Edit</a>"`